# Using regex to replace dot with slash in URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm using a front controller which uses URLs as follows:

http://www.domain.com/index.php?action=main.Main, 
where 'main' is the module and 'Main' is the action.

For URL rewrite I use this line in the htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA]
```

This results in http://www.domain.com/main.Main.html

Now, how do I replace the dot between module and action with a slash so that the result looks like this:
http://www.domain.com/main/Main ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this then:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?action=$1.$2 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ /$1.$2.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.+/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will take a request like: `http://www.domain.com/main/something/action/Main.html` and rewrite the URI to: `/index.php?action=main.something.action.Main`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: What you propose is that I separate module and action into separate variables, then your answer makes sense. However in my case, I have only one variable $1 which is 'module.action', and I want to to replace that dot with a slash.